# Как передать get-запрос другому моему сайту?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

Люди приходят на сайт №1 по ссылке: site1.com/?g=X , где X - это любое число.
Мне нужно передать этот get-параметр (g=X) сайту №2 ( site2.com ) в момент загрузки первого сайта.
Я имею доступ к обоим сайтам, и могу внедрить в них любые скрипты.

Как я понимаю, для решения этой проблемы, сайт №1 должен сделать одну из этих вещей:

- послать запрос на сайт №2.
- скрыто перейти на сайт №2.
- открыть/закрыть сайт в новом маленьком окне (не комильфо, и как я понимаю, всплывающие окна браузер может заблокировать.)
- использовать какое-то API.

Какой вариант наиболее оптимален и как его реализовать? Я нуб, поэтому буду благодарен любому коду :)

Comment: через фронтэнд - XMLHttpRequest (Fetch API), на бэкэнде - смотря по ситуации

Answer (score 1):

Первый вариант самый лучший. Некакой апи не нужен хватит jquery. делаете Ajax запрос асинхронный и все. не буду приводить пример ибо их в интернети полно. Надеюсь помог

Почитай:
[Пример AJAX](http://www.codernotes.ru/articles/javascript-jquery/ajax-zapros-k-serveru-cherez-jquery.html)

На сервере принимаешь данные как обычно.

Comment: ну хотя бы один пример для приличия привели бы)

Comment: @Александр Белинский Изменил ответ

Comment: да и jquery не нужно

Comment: с jquery будет легче

Answer (score 1):

первый вариант на чистом php

```
file_get_contents('http://site.ru/index.php?param='.$_GET['param']);
```